# Фильтрация запроса в postgreSQL (связь многие ко многим)

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Входные данные**: PostgreSQL. Есть 3 таблицы: `products`, `colors`, `products_to_colors`. Связь многие ко многим - каждый продукт может иметь несколько цветов. Каждый цвет может быть у нескольких продуктов. Связь между цветами и продуктами реализована с помощью 3 таблицы `products_to_colors`.

**Поля в таблицах**:

1. `products` - два поля: `id`, `name` (остальные не имеют значение, упрощаем задачу =) )
2. `colors` - 2 поля: `id`, `color` (в `color` указывается сам цвет, например, зелёный)
3. `products_to_colors` - 3 поля: `id`, `color_id`, `product_id`

**Я получаю** данные из таблиц с помощью такого запроса:

```
SELECT products.*, string_agg(colors.color, ',') AS colors
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN products_to_colors ON products.id = products_to_colors.product_id
    LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = products_to_colors.color_id
GROUP BY products.id
```

**Задача** состоит в том, чтобы получать из БД только те продукты, у которых есть определённый цвет.

**Например:** я хочу получить только те продукты, у которых доступен цвет с `id` 1:

```
SELECT products.*, string_agg(colors.color, ',') AS colors
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN products_to_colors ON products.id = products_to_colors.product_id
    LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = products_to_colors.color_id
WHERE products_to_colors.color_id=1
GROUP BY products.id
```

**Проблема.** Товары возвращаются правильно, только те, у которых доступен цвет с `id` 1, но, в колонке `colors` указывается только цвет с `id` 1. Хотя у товара так же есть цвета с `id` 2, 3, 4, но они отсутствуют в колонке `colors`.

Как мне исправить мой запрос к БД, чтобы получить желаемый результат?

Comment: подзапрос или самоджойн, в которому будут сначала выбраны id имеющие такой цвет.

Comment: а-ля `inner join (select distinct product_id from product_colors whre color_id = 1) on ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отбора продуктов, имеющих заданную характеристику, можно:

1. Добавить ещё одну копию таблицы для отбора:

```
SELECT products.*, string_agg(colors.color, ',') AS colors
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN products_to_colors ON products.id = products_to_colors.product_id
    LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = products_to_colors.color_id
    JOIN products_to_colors ptc ON products.id = ptc.product_id AND ptc.color_id=1
GROUP BY products.id
```

2. Посчитать для продукта количество записей с заданной характеристикой

```
SELECT products.*, string_agg(colors.color, ',') AS colors
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN products_to_colors ON products.id = products_to_colors.product_id
    LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = products_to_colors.color_id
GROUP BY products.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN products_to_colors.color_id=1 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и вникание в ситуацию! А какой из этих способов предпочтительнее? Возможно какой-то из них быстрее и требует меньше ресурсов?

Comment: Надо смотреть планы... например, если один на сотню продукт имеет заданную характеристику, предпочтительнее скорее всего первый, в если почти все - вероятно, второй.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под планами? Я делаю интернет магазин и пишу функцию, которая фильтрует товары. До этого работал с django, он всё делаем сам, теперь начал сам писать запросы и немного теряюсь

Comment: планы выполнения запросов

Comment: @Inventor План выполнения запроса. Грубо говоря, рассказ о том, как именно сервер будет получать результат. Пока просто протестируйте на более-менее реальных данных, если получите различие производительности в разы - пока временно выберите какой-то один... а тем временем поизучайте.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!